# postgres dump showing duplicate FUNCTION

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, postgresql-9.0

My postgres version is 9.0.4 I have created a postgres dump of my database and is containing duplicate entries of custom FUNCTIONS.When i directly query my database im not seeing any duplicates entry, but dump has this duplicates.

following is the list which i taken using pg_restore -l command.

```
37; 1255 16402 FUNCTION public sql_dirdepth(character varying) nidhin
31; 1255 16402 FUNCTION public sql_dirdepth(character varying) nidhin
29; 1255 16403 FUNCTION public sql_getdir(character varying) nidhin
35; 1255 16403 FUNCTION public sql_getdir(character varying) nidhin
30; 1255 16404 FUNCTION public sql_subdir(character varying, integer, integer) nidhin
36; 1255 16404 FUNCTION public sql_subdir(character varying, integer, integer) nidhin
32; 1255 16405 FUNCTION public unnest(anyarray) nidhin
38; 1255 16405 FUNCTION public unnest(anyarray) nidhin
```

I checked the functions inside DB and im not seeing any duplicate entries there.

```
CDB=# \df
                                      List of functions
 Schema |      Name       | Result data type  |         Argument data types         |  Type
--------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------+--------
 public | sql_dirdepth | integer           | character varying                   | normal
 public | sql_getdir   | character varying | character varying                   | normal
 public | sql_subdir   | character varying | character varying, integer, integer | normal
(3 rows)
```

So im wondering how the pg_dump has created duplicate entries of these functions in my dump file.

The query

```
SELECT * 
FROM pg_proc 
WHERE proname || '' IN ('unnest', 'sql_dirdepth', 'sql_getdir', 'sql_subdir');
```

gives the below result.

I can see duplicates in it,  How can I remove the duplicate functions?

```
|   proname    | pronamespace | proowner | prolang | procost | prorows | provariadic | proisagg | proiswindow | prosecdef | proisstrict | proretset | provolatile | pronargs | pronargdefaults | prorettype | proargtypes | proallargtypes | proargmodes | proargnames | proargdefaults |                                    prosrc                                    |         probin          | proconfig | proacl |
|--------------|--------------|----------|---------|---------|---------|-------------|----------|-------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|-----------------|------------|-------------|----------------|-------------|-------------|----------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------|-----------|--------|
| unnest       |           11 |       10 |      12 |       1 |     100 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | t           | t         | i           |        1 |               0 |       2283 |        2277 |                |             |             |                | array_unnest                                                                 |                         |           |        |
| sql_getdir   |         2200 |       10 |      13 |       1 |       0 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | t           | f         | i           |        1 |               0 |       1043 |        1043 |                |             |             |                | sql_getdir                                                                   | /opt/openkaz/lib/kazsql |           |        |
| sql_subdir   |         2200 |       10 |      13 |       1 |       0 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | t           | f         | i           |        3 |               0 |       1043 |  1043 23 23 |                |             |             |                | sql_subdir                                                                   | /opt/openkaz/lib/kazsql |           |        |
| sql_dirdepth |         2200 |       10 |      13 |       1 |       0 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | t           | f         | i           |        1 |               0 |         23 |        1043 |                |             |             |                | sql_dirdepth                                                                 | /opt/openkaz/lib/kazsql |           |        |
| unnest       |         2200 |       10 |      14 |     100 |    1000 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | f           | t         | i           |        1 |               0 |       2283 |        2277 |                |             |             |                | "select $1[i] from generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) i;" |                         |           |        |
| sql_subdir   |         2200 |       10 |      13 |       1 |       0 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | t           | f         | i           |        3 |               0 |       1043 |  1043 23 23 |                |             |             |                | sql_subdir                                                                   | /opt/openkaz/lib/kazsql |           |        |
| sql_dirdepth |         2200 |       10 |      13 |       1 |       0 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | t           | f         | i           |        1 |               0 |         23 |        1043 |                |             |             |                | sql_dirdepth                                                                 | /opt/openkaz/lib/kazsql |           |        |
| unnest       |         2200 |       10 |      14 |     100 |    1000 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | f           | t         | i           |        1 |               0 |       2283 |        2277 |                |             |             |                | "select $1[i] from generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) i;" |                         |           |        |
| sql_getdir   |         2200 |       10 |      13 |       1 |       0 |           0 | f        | f           | f         | t           | f         | i           |        1 |               0 |       1043 |        1043 |                |             |             |                | sql_getdir                                                                   | /opt/openkaz/lib/kazsql |           |        |
```

Comment: Postgres 9.0 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You should at least run 9.0.23 which was the last minor release for 9.0. You are missing 4.5 years of bugfixes between 9.0.4 and 9.0.23 - did you check if one of them maybe fixed this bug?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the output of `SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE proname || '' IN ('unnest', 'sql_dirdepth', 'sql_getdir', 'sql_subdir');`.

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the code for one of your own functions as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. Did you try to restore that dump? If yes, what happened? Does this also happen when you use a SQL dump?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Executed the query you have given and it shown duplicates.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Added the result in the quesition in csvc format, ,may i knw how if its okay to remove the duplicate function, and if yes how to do it..Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is catalog data corruption, since there are actually duplicate entries in the `pg_proc` catalog, even though there is a unique index that guarantees that the combination of schema name, function name and argument list are unique.

You should perform an immediate shutdown (crash the database) and take a physical backup of the data directory. This is always the first step when dealing with data corruption.

After restarting the database, take a text mode `pg_dumpall` of the cluster and manually remove the duplicate entries from the dump file. Restore the dump into a new cluster and remove the old one.

Once you have successfully got rid of the data corruption, you should immediately upgrade to PostgreSQL v12 **on new hardware**, because a version as old as 9.0 contains many known bugs that can cause all sorts of data corruption.

This is a prime example why upgrading is not just something invented by IT departments to keep themselves in a job and to annoy end users.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Is it a solution to delete the duplicate entry from the pg_proc table with the OID of the duplicate function.
like  delete from pg_proc where oid=17982;

Comment: our framework does the dump and restore using pg_dump & pg_restore so im thinking as a workaround if i can delete the entry from pg_proc and then do dump and restore, to see if it succeeds.

Comment: Messing with the catalogs is dangerous, but you are already up the proverbial creek, so it is an option. I still would do it the way I suggested, because there may be other problems as well. And *don't* continue using a cluster that had corruption, even if you "fixed" it. *Always* dump and restore.

Comment: Delete from pg_proc won't work as the OID itself is duplicate,also as u said it may have some risks in a direct delete from catalog .So my last try is to drop the duplicate custom functions using drop command and to see if the duplicate also get removed from pg_proc.and if it removes then i will create the function again ensurng that this time it has only one occurance in pg_proc. not sure if drop command remove the duplicate entries in the pg_proc , is this worth trying?

Comment: Sure, but then dump and restore. I cannot think of a failure mode where `oid`s are duplicate...